# Elastic property with windows phone slider

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, slider

I have a slider in windows phone as shown in figure. When I swipe the slider it's working. But what I want is, if I swipe the slider and leave it in the middle without reaching the end of the slider - it should return back to the beginning like elastic. If it was swiped to the end then it should navigate to the next page. Why I am using slider is, I need to control a text's opacity with animation.  How to do this task?

[image]

Comment: So you want someone to make an iPhone style unlock slider for you?

Answer (score 1):

I would use VisualStates to provide the animation, then you don't have to worry about the physics of it.  I have created a similar scenario for a notification style Windows Phone effect, you know how you can swipe a notification off to the right.  Basically it would be something like this:

1. `OnManipulationStarted` `VisualStateManager.GoToState` for OpenBegin or ClosedBegin depending on the state
2. `OnManipulationDelta` you can check `e.Delta.X` and if < 0 its moving left otherwise it's moving right or just check the position `OnManipulationCompleted`
3. After you know what the state call `VisualStateManager.GoToState` for OpenEnd or ClosedEnd and it will animate back to the specified location.

Add a comment if you need more help/code